# How do I copy a zip dependency to the target directory in an SBT build?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am working on an SBT project that generates an RPM via the `sat-native-packager`. One of the items that I want to pull into the RPM is a ZIP file that was published from a separate project using the `sat-pack` plugin. This ZIP file contains a number of JAR files, along with multiple scripts for invoking them.

I have the following in my RPM project's `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += ("com.mycompany" %% "aputils" % "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT").artifacts(Artifact("aputils", "zip", "zip"))

// Task to download and unpack the utils bundle
lazy val unpackUtilsTask = taskKey[Unit]("Download the utils bundle to the target directory")
unpackUtilsTask := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val report: UpdateReport = (update in Rpm).value
  val filter = artifactFilter(extension = "zip")
  val matches: Seq[File] = report.matching(filter)
  matches.foreach{ f =>
    log.info(s"Filter match: ${f}")
    IO.copyFile(f, target.value)
  }
}
```

When I run this task, it does not match any entries in the `UpdateReport`. Nothing is printed, and no files are copied to `target/`. If I modify the task to instead print all of the files in the `UpdateReport`:

```
report.allFiles.foreach(f => log.info(s"All files: $f))
```

I see a number of JAR files, but not my ZIP file. The JAR files turn out to be all of the JAR files that are contained in the ZIP file. I am not sure why the ZIP is being unpacked and its contents are being listed as dependencies like this. If I mark the dependency as `notTransitive`, then the contained JARs are not listed in the report, but the ZIP still isn't included either.

This project is using SBT 0.13.15. I would prefer not to update it to 1.x at this time, but will do so if I must.

I will need to unzip the ZIP file under `target/` eventually so I can define one or more `packageMapping` entries to pull the files into the RPM, but that seems easy enough to do via `sbt.IO`, if I can first just get a reference to the original ZIP file that is pulled down from our Artifactory server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This didn't get any responses after a couple days, but I'll post the answer that I was able to come up with after more trial and error.

I was on the right track by examining the `UpdateReport`, but I wasn't looking at the right data within it. I needed to drill down to find a `ModuleReport`, which would show me where the .zip file was being downloaded to on the build machine. Once I have that path, it is trivial to unpack it to `target/` using `IO.unzip()`. Here is how my task ended up looking:

```
libraryDependencies += ("com.mycompany" %% "aputils" % "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT").artifacts(Artifact("aputils", "zip", "zip"))

// Task to unzip the utils ZIP file to the target directory so we can define a package mapping
lazy val unpackUtilsTask = taskKey[Unit]("Download the utils bundle to the target directory")
unpackUtilsTask := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val cReport: ConfigurationReport = (update in Compile).value.configuration("compile").get
  cReport.modules.foreach{ mReport =>
    if (mReport.module.name.startsWith("aputils")) {
      mReport.artifacts.foreach{ case (art, f) =>
        log.info(s"Unpacking aputils bundle: ${f.getAbsolutePath}")
        IO.unzip(f, target.value)
      }
    }
  }
}
packageBin in Rpm := ((packageBin in Rpm).dependsOn(unpackUtilsTask)).value
```

The last line attaches the task to the task that builds the RPM, so it will be unzipped before the RPM is built, and we can define `packageMapping`s to put the contents of the .zip file into the generated RPM.

Comment: I had to change the next line to `packageBin in Compile := ((packageBin in Compile).dependsOn(unpackUtilsTask)).value`
`